# Can I connect the isolated grounds of multiple DC/DC converters together?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, ground, driver, igbt, isolated

I am working on a project that involves using isolated DC/DC converters to power gate driver ICs that will then switch on/off IGBTs. I have 9 DC/DC converters that will power 9 gate drivers each that will control 9 IGBTs each, so 1:1:1 ratio. The schematic below shows a pair of DC/DC converters and their respective gate drivers.

[image: A pair of DC/DC converters and their respective gate drivers.]

The IGBTs turn on/off by comparing the voltage difference between their respective gate driver V0 signal (pin 6) and VEE (pin 5), VEE is connected to the isolated ground from the DC/DC converter. My question is: can I connect the isolated grounds from multiple DC/DC converters together to create a "universal" isolated ground plane on a PCB so that the IGBTs compare the gate driver V0 signal (pin 6) to this single universal isolated ground plane (it's labeled in the schematic as "DCDC_GND")?

DC/DC converter datasheet: https://www.mornsun-power.com/html/pdf/B1524S-1WR3.html

Gate Driver datasheet: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/678/av01-0367en-1828059.pdf

IGBT datasheet: https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/fa/7a/3e/50/6e/a4/4b/f3/CD00058424.pdf/files/CD00058424.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00058424.pdf

I could test this but I don't have much time, I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: That depends how the IGBTs are wired. All with common emitters, yes.. Stacked (e.g. half-Bridge), no..